# Keycloak autologin after registration with direct link

Tags: keycloak

I have a spring boot web app with a direct [registration link](http://localhost:8888/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/registrations?response_type=code&response_mode=fragment&scope=openid&client_id=web&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9999%2Fuser) to keycloak.

My spring boot application.properties looks like this:

```
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8888/auth<br>
keycloak.realm=myrealm<br>
keycloak.public-client=true<br>
keycloak.principal-attribute=preferred_username<br>
keycloak.security-constraints[1].authRoles[0]=user<br>
keycloak.security-constraints[1].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/user<br>
```

A click on the link redirects me to keycloak where I can sign up. After registration I should have the default realm role user and should I be redirected to the restriced path http://localhost:9999/user. But after registration I don't have the role user and so I'm redirected back from /user to keycloak login page. When I login I have the role user and can access /user. 
Why doesn't direct login work when I use registration link?

Comment: And you have set up a default role assignement in your realm ? I do you have the same behaviour when enabling the "Register" link on the login screen and register from there ?

Comment: Yes, I have set up a default role 'user'. When I use the register link on the login screen registration works well.

Comment: I have similar kind of requirement where the user should be directly logged in to the system when verify email link is clicked. Instead of taking user to login page can we create a session automatically and redirect the user to intended redirect URI.

Comment: @kk did you ever figure that out?

Comment: @philk Nope, I've not figured this out.